# Trying to get the value of very next element of the current selected element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get the value of very next element of the current/selected element for example here is the list

```
<ul>
<li class="abc selected"><a href="www.test.com">test</a> </li>
<li class="abc"><a href="www.test1.com">test1</a> </li>
<li class="abc"><a href="www.test2.com">test2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

From the above code I am trying to get the value of "a" tag which is very next to the selected li, in above case I am try to get the value of a tag which is test1 and this "a" tag is within the very next li after the selected one.

I tried to use the jQuery below but its fetching the empty result. Any help

```
var linktext1= jQuery(".selected").next("li a").text();
alert (linktext1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector string passed to `.next` will filter out the next element if it doesn't match the selector string. But the next element is a `li`, not an `a`, so `.next('li a')` won't work.

Use `.next("li").find('a')` instead:

```js
var linktext1 = jQuery(".selected").next("li").find('a').text();
console.log(linktext1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="abc selected"><a href="www.test.com">test</a> </li>
  <li class="abc"><a href="www.test1.com">test1</a> </li>
  <li class="abc"><a href="www.test2.com">test2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

In this particular situation, though, there's no need for a `li` selector to pass to `.next`, because what is `.selected` will be a `li`, so any of its siblings will also be `li`s:

```js
var linktext1 = jQuery(".selected").next().find('a').text();
console.log(linktext1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="abc selected"><a href="www.test.com">test</a> </li>
  <li class="abc"><a href="www.test1.com">test1</a> </li>
  <li class="abc"><a href="www.test2.com">test2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove "li a" and it works. Below is the code

```
var linktext1= jQuery(".selected").next().text();
alert (linktext1);
```

Here is the example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmcshehan/6h579xa0/1/)